# WriteLine string containing '{' character throws FormatException in C#

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

This throws a FormatException:

`Console.WriteLine("strict digraph {0}\n{", project.ProjectName);`

But this is fine:

`Console.WriteLine("strict digraph {0}\n", project.ProjectName);`

I need the trailing '{' and `\{` isn't a valid escape code. What exactly is wrong with my code and how do I make it work?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("strict digraph {0}\n{{", project.ProjectName);`

Comment: In addition to the below answers, here's the MSDN article on "Composite Formatting" (the relevant section is a ways down, "Escaping Braces") http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to escape a curly bracket by another curly bracket:

```
Console.WriteLine("strict digraph {0}\n{{", project.ProjectName);
```

For further information have a look at the relevant MSDN article [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and its section "Escaping Braces".

Is states that

> Opening and closing braces are interpreted as starting and ending a format item. Consequently, you must use an escape sequence to display a literal opening brace or closing brace. Specify two opening braces ("{{") in the fixed text to display one opening brace ("{"), or two closing braces ("}}") to display one closing brace ("}"). Braces in a format item are interpreted sequentially in the order they are encountered. Interpreting nested braces is not supported.

But mind you. this can result in unexpected behavior: Take the format string `{{{0:D}}}` for example. It *should* output "{10}" for example, shouldn't it?. It should, but it doesn't. The MSDN-article linke above states that

> 1. The first two opening braces ("{{") are escaped and yield one opening brace.
> 2. The next three characters ("{0:") are interpreted as the start of a format item.
> 3. The next character ("D") would be interpreted as the Decimal standard numeric format specifier, but the next two escaped braces ("}}") yield a single brace. Because the resulting string ("D}") is not a standard numeric format specifier, the resulting string is interpreted as a custom format string that means display the literal string "D}".
> 4. The last brace ("}") is interpreted as the end of the format item.
> 5. The final result that is displayed is the literal string, "{D}". The numeric value that was to be formatted is not displayed.

To circumvent that MSDN suggests that to use the following code:

```
var result = string.Format("{0}{1:D}{2}", "{", 10, "}");
```